# web deploy parameterization in website project

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, iis, vs-web-site-project

I have tried web deploy parameterization using web application project(.NET 4.5.1) and it was successful. I have followed the steps mentioned in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068.aspx

But this method is not working for website project.!!!
Is this method is not applicable for website project?

Comment: I didn't know that web deploy even _worked_ for web site "projects". Can you deploy your project when you don't use parameters?

Comment: Project can be deployed successfully. But when tried to deploy the website project, the wizard is not prompting for the parameter configured in "parameters.xml". I tried the same in web application project, there it's prompting for the parameters..!!! Tried same method to deploy both packages, opened IIS, right click on the website>Deploy>Import Application. Please let me know if have done anything wrong...! @john Thanks for the comment...!

Comment: Good luck. You may be able to just compare the details of the two packages to get an idea of what the difference really is. But the ultimate solution is to simply never use web site "projects". Pretend they are just a horrible mistake that Microsoft made - which happens to be the truth.

Comment: This is a very big project and it's had to convert to web application... :( I will compare the packages. Please update me, If you get any clue..!!! Thanks @JohnSaunders

Comment: Still I am not able to figure it out, please help me...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Web.config" parameterisation is not possible in "website project" type in Visual Studio. See the Thread I posted in asp.net forum and the answer.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1998657.aspx?Web+deploy+parameterization+in+website+project

Please vote for the suggestion http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6210039-web-deploy-parameterization-in-website-project